# How can I make my test file work?

Tags: java, testing, extend

I have 3 class files:  Bin2Dec implements to throw an exception, BinaryFormatException is the exception file, and  bin2DecTest is the test file to test the correct operation of both the BinaryFormatException and bin2Dec. I don't know why but I can't get the test file to run. Someone please help me!!

TEST FILE:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class bin2DecTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Convert the input string to their decimal equivalent.
        //Open scanner for input.
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        //Declare variable s.
        String s;

        //Prompt user to enter binary string of 0s and 1s.
        System.out.print("Enter a binary string of 0s and 1s: ");
        //Save input to s variable.
        s = input.nextLine();
        //With the input, use try-catch blocks.
        //Print statement if input is valid with the conversion.
        try {
            System.out.println("The decimal value of the binary number " + "'" + s + "'" + " is " + conversion(s));
            //Catch the exception if input is invalid.
        } catch (BinaryFormatException e) {
            //If invalid, print the error message from BinaryFormatException.
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Bin2Dec FILE:

```
    //Prepare scanner from utility for input.
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Bin2Dec {
                  //Declare exception.

          public static int conversion(String parameter) throws BinaryFormatException {
            int digit = 0;

          for (int i = 0; i < parameter.length(); i++) {
              char wrong_number = parameter.charAt(i);


              if (wrong_number != '1' && wrong_number != '0') { 
                throw new BinaryFormatException("");
              }

              //Make an else statement and throw an exception.

              else 
                digit = digit * 2 + parameter.charAt(i) - '0';
            }
            return digit;
          } 
        }
```

BinaryFormatException FILE:

```
        //Define a custom exception called BinaryFormatException.
public class BinaryFormatException extends Exception {
    //Declare message.

    private String message;

    public BinaryFormatException(String msg) {
        this.message = msg;
    }
    //Return this message for invalid input to Bin2Dec class.

    public String getMessage() {
        return "Error: This is not a binary number";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code fails to compile because you are using `conversion` as if it was a method of `bin2DecTest`. You need to use `conversion` as a static method of `Bin2Dec`. E.g.

```
Bin2Dec.conversion(s);
```

Also, have a look at formal testing frameworks like [Junit](http://junit.org/) and [TestNG](http://testng.org/doc/index.html). They offer a few advantages over rolling your own simple test framework, including easy testing of code that throws an `Exception`.